# Update the dataframe with specific conditions

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe as below:

```
RankNumber  Value   Dept Number
  5          200    5
  4          200    5
  3          205    5
  2          198    5
  1          197    5
  5          200    6
  4          202    6
  3          205    6
  2          198    6
  1          194    6
```

I would like to update some of the cells from Value Column from dataframe. If the current "Value" is greater than previous value then it should get updated to previous value. If the "Value" is same or less than previous value then it should skip. It has been grouped by dept number.

I am trying to do this on pyspark, but cant find a way to accomplish that. Can someone please help??

Expected Results from dataframe is as below:

```
RankNumber  Value  Dept Number
  5         200     5
  4         200     5
  3         200     5 (record updated)
  2         198     5
  1         197     5
  5         200     6
  4         200     6 (record updated)
  3         200     6 (record updated)
  2         198     6
  1         194     6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your 8th row will get updated as '`3   202 6 (record updated)`' instead of
'`3   200 6 (record updated)`'. since it's previous value was '`202`' and current value '`205`' is greater than previous '`202`'.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w=Window.partitionBy("DeptNumber").orderBy(desc("RankNumber"))
df = df.withColumn('previous_value',F.coalesce(F.lag(df['value'],1).over(w),df['value']))
```

Below code will get the previous value if Value is greater than previous value.

```
newdf = df.select(df.RankNumber,df.DeptNumber,df.Value,df.previous_value,when( df.Value<=df.previous_value, df.Value).otherwise(df.previous_value).alias('newValue'))

>>> newdf.show()
+----------+----------+-----+--------------+--------+
|RankNumber|DeptNumber|Value|previous_value|newValue|
+----------+----------+-----+--------------+--------+
|         5|         6|  200|           200|     200|
|         4|         6|  202|           200|     200|
|         3|         6|  205|           202|     202|
|         2|         6|  198|           205|     198|
|         1|         6|  194|           198|     194|
|         5|         5|  200|           200|     200|
|         4|         5|  200|           200|     200|
|         3|         5|  205|           200|     200|
|         2|         5|  198|           205|     198|
|         1|         5|  197|           198|     197|
+----------+----------+-----+--------------+--------+
```

Below code will get the minimum of previous value as a new value.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc,when,lit

w=Window.partitionBy("DeptNumber").orderBy(desc("RankNumber"))

df = df.withColumn('previous_value',F.coalesce(F.lag(df['value'],1).over(w),df['value']))

newdf = df.select(df.RankNumber,df.DeptNumber,df.Value,df.previous_value,when( df.Value<=df.previous_value, df.Value) \
                        .when(F.lag(df['previous_value'],1).over(w)<=df.previous_value, F.first(df.previous_value).over(w)) \
                        .otherwise(df.previous_value).alias('newValue'))


>>> newdf.show()
+----------+----------+-----+--------------+--------+
|RankNumber|DeptNumber|Value|previous_value|newValue|
+----------+----------+-----+--------------+--------+
|         5|         6|  200|           200|     200|
|         4|         6|  202|           200|     200|
|         3|         6|  205|           202|     200|
|         2|         6|  198|           205|     198|
|         1|         6|  194|           198|     194|
|         5|         5|  200|           200|     200|
|         4|         5|  200|           200|     200|
|         3|         5|  205|           200|     200|
|         2|         5|  198|           205|     198|
|         1|         5|  197|           198|     197|
+----------+----------+-----+--------------+--------+
```

If you are looking a lowest value which is just above the previous value of that group then you need to changed a code like this.

```
newdf = df.select(df.RankNumber,df.DeptNumber,df.Value,df.previous_value,when( df.Value<=df.previous_value, df.Value) \
                        .when(F.lag(df['previous_value'],1).over(w)<=df.previous_value, F.lag(df['previous_value'],1).over(w)) \
                        .otherwise(df.previous_value).alias('newValue'))
```

This will results:

```
>>> newdf.show()
+----------+----------+-----+--------------+--------+
|RankNumber|DeptNumber|Value|previous_value|newValue|
+----------+----------+-----+--------------+--------+
|         5|     Dept2|  100|           100|     100|
|         4|     Dept2|  102|           100|     100|
|         3|     Dept2|  105|           102|     100|
|         2|     Dept2|  198|           105|     102|
|         1|     Dept2|  194|           198|     194|
|         5|     Dept1|  200|           200|     200|
|         4|     Dept1|  202|           200|     200|
|         3|     Dept1|  205|           202|     200|
|         2|     Dept1|  198|           205|     198|
|         1|     Dept1|  194|           198|     194|
+----------+----------+-----+--------------+--------+
```

**Update:**
Now creating a new dataframe as mentioned in the comment section below:

```
listOfTuples = [(5, 200, "Dept1"), (4, 202, "Dept1"), (3, 205, "Dept1"), (2, 198, "Dept1"), (1, 194, "Dept1") , (5, 100, "Dept2"), (4, 102, "Dept2"), (3, 105, "Dept2"), (2, 198, "Dept2"), (1, 194, "Dept2") ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(listOfTuples , ["RankNumber", "Value", "DeptNumber"])


>>> df.show()
+----------+-----+----------+
|RankNumber|Value|DeptNumber|
+----------+-----+----------+
|         5|  200|     Dept1|
|         4|  202|     Dept1|
|         3|  205|     Dept1|
|         2|  198|     Dept1|
|         1|  194|     Dept1|
|         5|  100|     Dept2|
|         4|  102|     Dept2|
|         3|  105|     Dept2|
|         2|  198|     Dept2|
|         1|  194|     Dept2|
+----------+-----+----------+
```

I believe your intention is to look in a range between current and preceding row and pick the lowest value if first condition get satisfied. ie: value is greater than previous value.

```
w1=Window.partitionBy("DeptNumber").orderBy(desc("RankNumber"))
w2=Window.partitionBy("DeptNumber").orderBy(desc("RankNumber")).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

df = df.withColumn('previous_value',F.coalesce(F.lag(df['value'],1).over(w1),df['value']))
```

here's your code:

```
newdf = df.select(df.RankNumber,df.DeptNumber,df.Value,df.previous_value,when( df.Value<=df.previous_value, df.Value) \
                        .otherwise(F.min(df.previous_value).over(w2)).alias('newValue'))

>>> newdf.show()
+----------+----------+-----+--------------+--------+
|RankNumber|DeptNumber|Value|previous_value|newValue|
+----------+----------+-----+--------------+--------+
|         5|     Dept2|  100|           100|     100|
|         4|     Dept2|  102|           100|     100|
|         3|     Dept2|  105|           102|     100|
|         2|     Dept2|  198|           105|     100|
|         1|     Dept2|  194|           198|     194|
|         5|     Dept1|  200|           200|     200|
|         4|     Dept1|  202|           200|     200|
|         3|     Dept1|  205|           202|     200|
|         2|     Dept1|  198|           205|     198|
|         1|     Dept1|  194|           198|     194|
+----------+----------+-----+--------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Vikrant for your response, you got this right . Saying that 7th record " 4 , 202,  6" will get updated to 6th record as "4 , 200,  6". As 5th record's value is lesser than 6th record value Is this making sense?

Comment: Thanks. so you are expecting output as mentioned in the question. I think it can be done. There has to be one more lag. I will give it a try once get on to the system. :-)

Comment: I get what you saying, may be something like this.. will solve the problem ```df = df.withColumn('prepre_value',F.coalesce(F.lag(df['previous_value'],1).over(w),df['previous_value']))``` but how do we know the number of lags to be applied as this needs to be done dynamically and cannot take a call looking at dataset. Appreciate your help

Comment: sure .. no worries. Take your time

Comment: can you check the updated answer? I have tested it and it's working fine.

Comment: I tried with different dataset   and it is not working as expected. Can you run the code with below df?                                                                                          `listOfTuples = [(5, 200, "Dept1"),
  (4, 202, "Dept1"),
  (3, 205, "Dept1"),
  (2, 198, "Dept1"),
  (1, 194, "Dept1") ,
  
  (5, 100, "Dept2"),
  (4, 102, "Dept2"),
  (3, 105, "Dept2"),
  (2, 198, "Dept2"),
  (1, 194, "Dept2") 
  ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(listOfTuples , ["RankNumber", "Value", "DeptNumber"])`

Comment: No. It's working as expected as per the rules " If the current "Value" is greater than previous value then it should get updated to previous value. If the "Value" is same or less than previous value then it should skip" see output above.

Comment: I was referring to record " rankNumber = 1, DeptNumber = Dept2" the newValue is 194. Where as the previous row with RankNumber = 2 has NewValue as 100. Never mind,I have marked this as answered and completed.I will sort out the rest. Thank you soo very much for your effort and help! much appreciated! Have a nice day

Comment: I have updated the answer at the end. I hope this's what you were looking for. Please check. we need to define two windows in order to solve this. Thanks